# How to make bootstrap column height to 100% row height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I haven't found a suitable solution to this and it seems so trivial.

I have two columns inside a row:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="left-side">
      <p>sdfsdf</p>
      <p>sdfsdf</p>
      <p>sdfsdf</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="something">asdfdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The row height is set by the larger row, `left-side`. However, I want the right side's height to be the same.

This seems intuitive, but it doesn't work

```
.left-side {
    background-color: blue;
}
.something {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.row {
    background-color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ccorcos/jz8j247x/

Comment: you want to do it with css? or can use jquery?

Comment: I saw that other post. But its different. They're using a table to make a header, sidebar, content layout

Comment: can someone unmark this question as duplicate? I have another solution that might help...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can solve that using **display** table.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/alansouzati/Le24d7py/) is the updated JSFiddle that solves your problem.

**CSS**

```
.body {
    display: table;
    background-color: green;
}

.left-side {
    background-color: blue;
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.right-side {
    background-color: red;
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row body">
        <div class="col-xs-9 left-side">
            <p>sdfsdf</p>
            <p>sdfsdf</p>
            <p>sdfsdf</p>
            <p>sdfsdf</p>
            <p>sdfsdf</p>
            <p>sdfsdf</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 right-side">
            asdfdf
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: beautiful. Are there any drawbacks to this? I've never seen a `display: table` honestly

Comment: There are drawbacks. Say you want this page to render at col-md-9 and col-md-3, but for mobile, you want each container to be full-width. You now need a bunch of media queries to fix your table-layout solution. Also, media queries are not supported in IE8 and below.

Comment: whats this obsession with being IE compatible? lol

Comment: How do you make the row also 100% height, and also the body,so it take all window?

Comment: @Chet IE is still a browser in widespread international use. If you are doing a public website you'd be mad not to support it, albeit a pain

Comment: Better support Opera too then, right? http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: @Chet So you don't support FF then? http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser-ww-monthly-201412-201512

Comment: At this point in time, you would not be mad to drop support for IE 8 and below. I'd say even IE 9 and below. Though you would be wise to detect that an older browser is being used and advise your users to upgrade rather than displaying a broken site.

Comment: Even with those stats, unless you can convince your client (or they definitely need it), then you (I) have no choice but to support it.

Comment: This solution does not work anymore. The columns do not respect the proportions given. Now the two columns have the same width. Any solution for the current version of browsers and bootstrap?

Comment: I don't think this is the proper solution, 'cos we cannot take advantage of Bootstrap wide grid

Answer (score 26):

@Alan's answer will do what you're looking for, but this solution fails when you use the responsive capabilities of Bootstrap. In your case, you're using the `xs` sizes so you won't notice, but if you used anything else (e.g. `col-sm`, `col-md`, etc), you'd understand.

Another approach is to play with margins and padding. See the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jz8j247x/1/

```
.left-side {
  background-color: blue;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: -1000px;
  height: 100%;
}
.something {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: -1000px;
  height: 100%;
}
.row {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Not bad, but if I were to put, say, a Google Map in there with `height: 100%`, then I'd have a huge map that isnt entirely visible...

Comment: you could always wrap your map in another container and size that. you have to keep in mind this is just styling 'this' container.

Comment: @Esteban - This is a good solution as it solves the responsive problem, however it doesn't allow you to have any styling at the bottom of the elements (e.g. bottom border). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: yeah.. that's a drawback to this approach. You can add a border to the outer containing row, and to the div with the full height, but not the shorter div that you are trying to expand. See http://jsfiddle.net/jz8j247x/30/

Comment: This will not work past 1000px, so it's not that helpful for larger sets of data.

Comment: @Rick change it to 2000px, 3000px? It's just a hacky workaround for a specific problem. You could always use flexbox too.