# Fill up div with full-height image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website with on the front page a div that is split up in two with the Twitter Bootstrap grid-system. Whenever the 2nd grid (`span9`) is higher than the 1st (`span3`), the image fills up the `span9` beautifully (the images has `width:100%`).

[image]

If I resize the page however, the text in the `span3` takes up more lines and makes the whole `div` higher than the image, resulting in the following:

[image]

Of course I want the image to fill up the complete height of the div, without stretching the image vertically (hey, it's not the 90s anymore!). However, I can't find out how to do this through CSS, without the image breaking out of the div in width.

What I want is that the image crops/clips from the right side and grows vertically every time the div gets less wide, but higher.

I tried setting up a fiddle, but because Bootstrap jumps to the mobile CSS in the small window, I can't replicate it unless you use fullscreen and resize your browser: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zt76m7t6/1/)

Of course you can also just see it [live](http://kursus.billetten.dk/).

Comment: would it be ok to 'stretch' the image?

Comment: Well, no. As I mention `without stretching the image`. That's why I want to crop.

Comment: Perhaps you could use two different images. One cropped to fit the div's height on resizing?

Comment: The div resizes with the window, so I can't work with one cropped image, unless I make it 366px high, the maximum height of that div before it jumps to mobile view. I might try it out if it's not possible to fix differently.

Answer (score 1):

check if your span-9 already gets the full height of the parent (it should), if so, make the image a background image using css (or even a short inline `style="background-image: url(...)"`) and then scale it using

```
.fullheightimg{
    background-size: cover;
    background-positon: center right;
}
```

Resources and further reading by Mozilla:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images

> The cover value specifies that the background image should be sized so
>   that it is as small as possible while ensuring that both dimensions
>   are greater than or equal to the corresponding size of the container.

This should be a full blown example of your problem:

```
@media (min-width: 970px) {
  .banner .row-fluid {
    display: table;
  }
  .banner .row-fluid .span3, .banner .row-fluid .span9 {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
.banner .row-fluid .fullimage {
  background-image: url('http://santamonicacentric.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/internet-famous-grumpy-cat-just-landed-an-endorsement-deal-with-friskies.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center left;
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: But this will stretch the image, won't it? Going to try it out now.

Comment: background-size: cover prevents the image from being stretched. it just scales proportionally. You might want to position the background `center left` for the W+K Logo though.

Comment: I've [edited](http://jsfiddle.net/zt76m7t6/2/) the original fiddle, but the image still seem not to take full div height.

Comment: actually bootstraps grid is quite bad when it comes to full height divs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213171/how-to-make-bootstrap-column-height-to-100-row-height) but there is a workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/danielwinter/zt76m7t6/3/ - You will need media queries for using this just on bigger devices though as it will break your breakpoints. I would suggest using purecss.io for a minimal grid. By using min-height on the fullimage you may further increase the minimum height of the image.

Comment: i edited my answer with a full solution for your site.

Comment: What HTML would you use to accompany your CSS? I can't get it to work.

Comment: you need to add the class fullimage to your span9 directly.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer of Danielwinter didn't work, I had to continue playing on my own and found the following situation.

I know that the mobile style will be applied from 767px browser-width and below, and the image would have to resize from a browser width of 1223px and below.

In the HTML I added a new `div` with class `banner_image`. This div will get the image as a `background` with `size` set to `cover`.

**CSS**

```
.banner_image {
   background: url(http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/themes/kurser/img/header_image.jpg) no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

The normal image (put in with `<img>`-tags) should disappear as soon as the image is supposed to resize with the new div. To make sure the image doesn't have a static height, I even the height of the `div` with text to the height of the image with some jQuery. To prevent the image keeping it's size when the window gets resized, I copy-pasted the complete code into a function that runs when the window gets resized.

**jQuery**

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth > 768 && windowWidth < 1223){
    $('.banner_image').show();
    $('.banner_image').height($('.banner .span3').height());
    $('.banner .span12 img').hide();            
}
else {
    $('.banner_image').hide();
    $('.banner .span12 img').show();
}

$(window).resize(function() {
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(windowWidth > 768 && windowWidth < 1223){
        $('.banner_image').show();
        $('.banner_image').height($('.banner .span3').height());
        $('.banner .span12 img').hide();                
    }
    else {
        $('.banner_image').hide();
        $('.banner .span12 img').show();
    }
});
```

By doing it this way, the image resizes when the windows is resized, the original `<img>` is hidden when between a certain width and it just creates the overall best experience for the user.